# iPhone file names

Tags: iphone, xcode

Is there any option to disable file names being case sensitive on iPhone? And if there isn't such option is there any way to rename all files that are copied in the application bundle to use only lowercase? I have many files that have upper cases and lower cases in their names and when I'm trying to open them from my application I use only lower case names and the file are not found. I can't change the file opening process now because it's an engine that works on windows/xbox/ps3.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a specific file renaming tool, or since you are on a Mac you could always delve into **Automator** to create a purpose built method for changing the case of all your files.
[Here's an applicable tutorial](http://www.chriswrites.com/2009/04/how-to-use-automator-to-mass-rename-finder-items/)

You can have this all set up within 5 minutes and get back to concentrate on your code, without having to do a mass refactor within your codebase.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "application bundle" I presume you mean images and such in your app. In that case, I suggest you use whatever tools you have to rename them to lower case and live with the lost time taken to do that. Win won't whine, and the iPhone will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can always rename your resources manually before adding to the project to be lowercase only.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know a method to disable it. But you can use the following method of NSString:

```
[@"Filename.ext" lowercaseString];
```

This returns a lowercase String. Try to make a for loop trough all of your files and rename them. ;-)